# Get data from WooCommerce protected object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to get specific data from `wc_get_orders()`.

Here is the code:

```
$args   = array(
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
echo '<pre>', var_dump( $orders ), '</pre>';
```

Here is the part of the object:

```
["meta_data":protected]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(WC_Meta_Data)#3544 (2) {
        ["current_data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1135)
          ["key"]=>
          string(13) "is_vat_exempt"
          ["value"]=>
          string(2) "no"
        }
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1135)
          ["key"]=>
          string(13) "is_vat_exempt"
          ["value"]=>
          string(2) "no"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(WC_Meta_Data)#3545 (2) {
        ["current_data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1136)
          ["key"]=>
          string(13) "tip_korisnika"
          ["value"]=>
          string(13) "Fizičko lice"
        }
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1136)
          ["key"]=>
          string(13) "tip_korisnika"
          ["value"]=>
          string(13) "Fizičko lice"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(WC_Meta_Data)#3546 (2) {
        ["current_data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1137)
          ["key"]=>
          string(12) "fs4e_methods"
          ["value"]=>
          string(5) "obuka"
        }
        ["data":protected]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1137)
          ["key"]=>
          string(12) "fs4e_methods"
          ["value"]=>
          string(5) "obuka"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
```

I'm trying to get the value of `tip_korisinka`, which is inside `WC_Meta_Data` that is protected. Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/CI-UfqEkuuag

This is the one of the solutions without success that I have tried so far:

```
foreach ( $orders as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key->$value['tip_korisnika'];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use the appropriate getter method. https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_get_meta_data

Comment: @CBroe Can you provide an example of how to get it? I already check that and I still need help.

Comment: `$key->$value` makes no sense whatsoever. You are looping over an array $orders, so with that foreach syntax, each individual order is accessible via `$value` inside your loop.

Comment: @CBroe, I know, I tried it already. I'm looking for a hint of how I can achieve it.

Comment: You have an instance of a specific class, and that class provides a certain method. Do you not know how you call a class method on an instance? `$value->get_meta_data()`. That will get you the array of `WC_Meta_Data` instances ... since those have their properties protected as well, you will need to continue by calling the appropriate getter methods for _those_ properties next then.